# Partial Differential equations and applications- Reference request

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, finance

I will be taking up a PDEs course next semester and would like to find some good references. The topics covered in the syllabus is given below.

> Partial differential equations: Conservation laws, classifications,
>   elementary analytical methods, initial/ boundary value problems.
>   Diffusion equation: Fundamental solution, similarity solution,
>   qualitative behavior of diffusion initial value problems, Cauchy
>   problem with infinite domain, Initial boundary value problems in the
>   semi- infinite domain, Green’s function, homogeneous boundary value
>   problem with inhomogeneous boundary condition. Hyperbolic equations:
>   Characteristic methods, initial value problems with non- continuous
>   initial data, introduction to weak solutions. Basic option theory:
>   Call option, put option, Asian option, Black – Sholes model and its
>   derivatives. Numerical methods: Discretization of derivatives,
>   boundary conditions, grids, finite difference methods for initial/
>   boundary value problems, consistency, stability, convergence,
>   applications of finite difference methods in financial derivatives.
>
> I hope someone could suggest a some reference books or maybe even a single book that may cover the above topics. Thanks and looking forward for some assistance. Cheers

Comment: Suggest you get any engineering/physics book and do exercises in explicit solutions for the heat equation using Fourier series. Not sure where to send you for one-dimensional wave equation. Anyway, all your stuff is one space dimension, no transforms, no elliptic, but it would appear they will never be showing you anything that has a closed-form solution, so your comfort level will improve if you practice such. Just remembered, vibrating string from physics, good example for this.

Comment: Weinberger's [**A First Course in Partial Differential Equations: with Complex Variables and Transform Methods**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/048668640X) is a good reference to have that is mathematically solid (i.e. uniform convergence is explicitly dealt with) without being beyond the level of the typical undergraduate physics/engineering separation-of-variables PDE text. The Dover reprint is also quite cheap. I took a beginning graduate course that used this back in Fall 1989, and I think the hardback version cost over $60 back then.

Comment: Partial Differential Equations: Second Edition Graduate Studies in Mathematics. Excellent book with many examples and exercises.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For something that has a little bit of everything, check out Partial Differential Equations by Walter A Strauss

It is a great intro to all of these topics.

For more in depth references, I reccommend these to anyone studying this field:

Partial Differential Equations- Lawrence C Evans

Numerical Solution of Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction- Morton, K. W.

Numerical Methods to Conservation Laws- Randall J. Leveque

Green's Functions and Boundary Value Problems - Ivar Stakgold

Answer (score 3):

A nice book focused on examples and treating much of the classical families of PDE step by step is the *Partial Differential Equations* of L. C. Evans. It seems to cover near all your syllabus, maybe without the discretization part.

Whatever, it is typically a good first course companion.

Hoping it will be of some help.